# Zend 1.12 & PHPUnit some files are not loaded

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm trying to test my services with PHPUnit (3.7) on ZF 1.12
When I test a service which call a DAO, the DAO is not found.
I've tried many things but always an error:

**Bootstrap.php**

```
define('TESTS_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('APPLICATION_LIBRARY_PATH', TESTS_PATH . '/../../php-deps');
define('APPLICATION_PATH', TESTS_PATH . '/../application');
define('LIBRARY_PATH', APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library');
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'http://link.local';

$includePaths = array(  APPLICATION_PATH,
                        LIBRARY_PATH,
                        APPLICATION_LIBRARY_PATH,
                        TESTS_PATH,
                        get_include_path(),
                    );
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $includePaths));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
require_once 'model/Service/Abstract.php';

Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('Application');
Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled = true;
Zend_Session::start();
```

**My files**

```
├───model
│   ├───Common
│   ├───Dao
│   ├───Entity
│   │   ├───Abstract
│   │   └───Interface
│   └───Service
│       ├───Administration
│       ├───Dev
│       ├───Exception
├───test
│   └───application
│       ├───library
│       │   └───Classes
│       └───model
│           └───Service
│               ├───Administration
│               ├───Collaborators
│               ├───Mission
│               └───Planning
```

Any idea is welcome !

Comment: what namespace and class name do you put inside the classes inside Dao ? and, are the other classes (model/Entity) loaded OK ?

Comment: I have not any namespace in my app. The services are load. And my entities are not load too.